# How to kill the cherrypy process?

Tags: python, cherrypy, kill-process

I am using `cherrypy` in python script.I think I have to register a callback method from the main application so that i can stop cherrypy main process from a worker thread,but how do i kill the main process within the that process.

So i want to know how to stop `cherrypy` from within the main process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
import sys

class CherryPyApp(object):

  def default(self):
    sys.exit()
  default.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(CherryPyApp())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your process is using CherryPy to block (via quickstart or engine.block), then you could simply call: `cherrypy.engine.exit()` from your page handler. That would be the cleanest option since it would properly terminate CherryPy and plugins you may have subscribed to.